# C# Declaring Multiple Instances of the Same Table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table that needs 27 drop down menus in 27 cells to accept user input.  Currently I am declaring all 27 of them like this:

```
DropDownList DropList1 = new DropDownList();
DropList1.ID = "TrendList1";
DropList1.AutoPostBack = true;
DropList1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.Selection_Change);
DropList1.DataSource = CreateDataSource();
DropList1.DataTextField = "ColorTextField";
DropList1.DataValueField = "ColorValueField";
DropList1.DataBind();

DropDownList DropList2 = new DropDownList();
DropList2.ID = "TrendList2";
DropList2.AutoPostBack = true;
DropList2.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.Selection_Change);
DropList2.DataSource = CreateDataSource();
DropList2.DataTextField = "ColorTextField";
DropList2.DataValueField = "ColorValueField";
DropList2.DataBind();

etc...
```

However I know there has to be a better way than the brute force code I have written.  Unfortunately I am new to web programming and I haven't been able to figure out a better way to do this.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = CreateDataSource();

for(x = 1; x < 28; x++)
{
    DropDownList dl = new DropDownList();
    dl.ID = "TrendList" + x.ToString();
    dl.AutoPostBack = true;
    dl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.Selection_Change);
    dl.DataSource = data;
    dl.DataTextField = "ColorTextField";
    dl.DataValueField = "ColorValueField";
    dl.DataBind();
    // add it to the cell here too
}
```

Comment: This assumes that `CreateDataSource()` is deterministic (will return the same thing each time it is called), but otherwise it is certainly the proper solution. If `CreateDataSource()` does something non-obvious, for instance returning a new data source each time it is called and incrementing a counter, or whatever, you'd want to keep it in the body of the loop. (Given the description, I don't think this is the case, but it isn't clear either way.)

Comment: Thanks.  I should have also asked how to automate these as well:
`if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DropList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            etc...
        }`
and
`p1.Controls.Add(DropList1);
 p2.Controls.Add(DropList2);
 etc...`
            DropList2.SelectedIndex = 0;

Comment: There wasn't enough information to determine if the datasource is the same for every DropDownList

Comment: The datasource is the same for all DropDownLists.  I have PlaceHolders in my table that I want to instantiate with the DropDownLists but this bit of code (added to what's above) is throwing a runtime error: `PlaceHolder ph = (PlaceHolder)form1.FindControl("p" + x.ToString());
            ph.Controls.Add(dl);`

Comment: I should add that the PlaceHolders have sequential IDs: p1, p2, ..., p27.

Comment: Actually, the first DropDownList will work no matter which one is selected.  The runtime error occurs when you try to select a value in a second DropDownList.

Comment: Don't find control on the Form, FindControl on the page.  Are you using a MasterPage?